# Ajax: Not able to detect event or console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am creating the event but not able to detect the event using Ajax. I am working on Codeigniter and  I have the following code:-

> View.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#promocode").on("input",function(){
    console.log('handler detected');
    var valueModel = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url : "bookings/getVCode",
      type: "post",
      data: {"valueModel":valueModel},
      success : function(data){
        // console.log(data);
        $("#msg").html(data);
      },
    });
});
</script>

<label for="promocode">Promo Code</label><div id="msg"></div>
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="promocode" name="promocode" >
```

**My Controller:**

> Bookings.php

```
function getVCode()
{
    $data = $this->NewQuoteModel->checkVoucherexist();
    $option =""; 

    if(count($data) > 0){
        $option .="<p> Your Voucher is Valid! </p>"; 
    } else {
        $option .= "<p> Your Voucher is not Valid! </p>"; 
    }
            echo $option; 
}
```

**And My Modal**

> NewQuoteModel.php

```
 function checkVoucherexist()
{
    $model = $this->input->post('valueModel');  
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('Vouchers');
    $this->db->where('Name', $model);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        //echo 'No Make found';
    }

}
```

Comment: When `$("#promocode")` executes, there is no element with that ID so it binds to nothing.

Comment: @user10345537 use "keydown" or "change" kind of events instead of "input" event of textbox

Comment: thanks @Phil. I was placing the <script> above the element so I was not getting any response. But Now I have placed it below, I am able to get the response but I am not able to get the log. I am only getting the HTML coding in the Web Browser console instead showing msg in the browser console

Comment: What _"log"_ are you referring to?

Comment: @Dhiren why? `"input"` is a very versatile event and looks perfect for this

Comment: @Dhiren I have changed it `change` .

Comment: @Dhiren I am referring to`console.log(data)`. When I check in the browser console, I get `<html><head></head></body>` code and an error that says:  TypeError: Bootstrap tooltips require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)

Comment: @Dhiren did u get my point? thanks

Comment: No worries. I have figured out and its working now